# Programatically accessing chrome devtools network API from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

As described in the documentation the performance metrics can be fetched using the [navigation and resource timings API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings).

I've had varying levels of success using the `PerformanceObserver` as shown in the [webdev tutorials](https://web.dev/user-centric-performance-metrics/#important-metrics-to-measure). However, I was either unable to find the information shown in the footer, or my timings did not match the timings of the DevTools. I have been unable to find any straightforward solutions.

**How do I fetch the footer information shown below from javascript using the API?** (marked red in the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RxWs.png))

- 22 requests
- 428 kB transferred
- 1.78 MB resources
- Finish: 3.47 s
- DOMContentLoaded: 1.41 s
- Load: 1.75 s

Thank you.